# Handling Fault Exception globally at client side and showing custom js popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, wcf

My WCF service is throwing Unauthenticated & Unauthorised Fault Exception based on some validation. I want to handle these fault exceptions globally and then show them using a custom JS popup.

Is there any way to do this at global level.

Comment: Take a look at the [IErrorHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx) - this will allow you to handle errors globally at the service level.

Comment: Hello Tim, I have implemented it to handle the exceptions at service side,  but I want to catch those exception at ASP.NET web application globally. Please help me...

Comment: Take a look at the Application_Error method in Global.asax.